# How to Loop through a string and return a new string that stops at a specific character

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Getting back into Python after a 2 year hiatus. Don't remember the best way to loop through a string from the beginning and stopping at a certain character, then returning the string.

```
def my_string(long_string, char):

    newstr = " "
    for i in range(len(long_string)):
       if long_string[i] == char:
           # now what?
```

I know I need to create a new string, then start a loop to go through the existing string. But then I get stuck. I know I need to return the new string, but am not sure what the rest of my code should look like. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: is that _certain character_ guaranteed in the string? Do you want to include the certain character in the new string or stop just before it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get the substring from the beginning of the long string until a certain char, you can just do the following:

```
>>> ch = 'r'
>>> s = 'Hello, world!'
>>> print(s[:s.find(ch)])
#  Hello, wo
```

Comment: This doesn't work for the case where ch is not in s: `c,s='r','Who fwamed wodgew wabit?'; s[:s.find(c)]` gives: `'Who fwamed wodgew wabit'` (note the missing questionmark)...

Answer (score 1):

Use a string slice to grab the portion of the string you want. From your description it sounds like you want all characters up to the first occurrence of that character correct?

Try this for example. Tweak the indices to get the portion of the string you want.

`long_string[0:i]`

The answers that include the use of .index() will not work well if the target character doesn't exist in the string without catching the exception.

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    print d[:d.index('y')]
except ValueError:
    print d
```

Comment: you probably want to return the entire string in that case. And writing `except ValueError` would be a tiny bit better

Answer (score 0):

If the stop character is definitely in the string you can use `.index()` which will find the index of the first occurrence of the thing in brackets and slicing `[]`

```
string = "hello op"
stopchar = " "

newstr = string[:string.index(stopchar)]

#newstr = "hello"
```

If you're not sure if the stop character is in the string you should use `.find()` which will not raise an error if it does not find the character:

```
newstr = string[:string.find(stopchar)]
```

If you don't want to stop at the first character and want to get all words before the stop character you could use this list comprehension:

```
string2 = "hello op today"
strings = [string2[:i] for i,c in enumerate(string2)
           if c == stopchar]
print (strings)
```

result:

```
['hello', 'hello op']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list containing each char in the string and loop through the list.

```
mystr = raw_input("Input: ")
newStr = list(mystr)

print(newStr)
```

Then you can just loop through the list to meet your conditions

Comment: You can index just find on strings in python there is no need to convert it to a list first.

Answer (score 0):

I think `split` works better than `index` (returns error if character not found) or `find` (returns -1 if character isn't found).

```
>>> s,c='Who fwamed wodgew wabit?','w'
>>> s.split(c)[0]
'Who f'
>>> c='r'
>>> s.split(c)[0]
'Who fwamed wodgew wabit?'
```

Explanation: `split` [returns a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). By returning the first item, this works exactly as specified.